# How to upload an Evernote ENML note using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, evernote

I'm trying to upload a Note with Evernote API 2.0 in Swift... I've made an ENML note and tried to update, but the upload method for ENSession accepts just plaintext notes. Therefore, the resultant note in Evernote Sandbox is a full of ENML tags... does anybody know how to upload an ENML Note using Swift?

Code is shown below:

```
    let static_text = "<en-note><span style=\"font-weight:bold;color:red;\">Hello World</span></en-note>"

    var note = ENNote()
    note.title = getCurrentDate()
    note.content = ENNoteContent(string: static_text)

    ENSession.sharedSession().uploadNote(note, notebook: nil, completion: { noteRef, error in
            if error == nil {
                println("OK")
            } else {
                println("Upload note error: \(error)")
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you import `ENSDK/Advanced/ENSDKAdvanced.h` (This might already be imported depending on how you added the Evernote SDK), you will have access to a new method on `ENNoteContent` ([Source on github](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/66de36c5159cb8043ed1d9004de9531657480879/evernote-sdk-ios/ENSDK/Advanced/ENSDKAdvanced.h#L177)):

```
+ (instancetype)noteContentWithENML:(NSString *)enml;
```

Assuming my Swift translation is correct (it might not be), this would mean you need to use:

```
note.content = ENNoteContent(ENML: static_text)
```

to set your note's content.

Comment: Thanks a lot... with the importing of `ENSDKAdvanced.h`, there is this new constructor:  `ENMLContent (ENML: text)`. I have tested with that code sample and it worked!

Comment: Sorry... StackOverflow newbie! :)